# Отслеживание UTM ссылки в Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

В Google Play имеется приложение, например, Test123. Для него, с помощью Google-генератора была сгенерированна UTM-ссылка вида:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.test123&referrer=utm_source%3Demail

По идее переходы по этой ссылке должны отображаться в Play Console в разделе Источники трафика -> Отчеты по источникам трафика -> Отслеживаемые каналы (UTM)

Вопрос 1:
Корректная ли эта ссылка и должны ли быть отображены клики по ней в "Отслеживаемых каналах" в Play Console

Вопрос 2:
Если некто в рассылке заменил ссылку на другую (редирект через битриксовый сайт) будут ли эти ссылки учитываться в Play Console? Ссылка вида:

http://osnovnoysite.ru/bitrix/tools/track_mail_click.php?tag=sender.eyJSRUNJUElFTlRfSUQiOjB9&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dru.test123%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Demail%26bx_sender_conversion_id%3D0&sign=5e4f2cf93db60965769b8a3186d0414febb2ff329a406452d15beb1bafbfa399

Comment: Браузеры вроде  как не передают инфы, что был перенаправлены на  адрес. Посему всё должно учитываться. Единственное, что может быть http-referer если перенаправление произошло с помощью javascript.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич А можно это как то проверить?

Comment: можно. открыть браузер, консоль разработчика... в Network увидеть запросы.